# Can a "shorter-than-usual" entry stamp be extended?

Tags: borders, overstaying, passport-stamps, paraguay

I entered Paraguay by land and they gave me 15 days instead of 90 days. It was due to the fact that it looked suspicious to them that I didn't have hotel reservations for all of my stay. But I never book in advance for a whole stay; instead I'll book for 1-2 days and then either change a hotel or keep staying there paying directly.

1. In this situation, can I go to the immigration in Asuncion and ask them to extend my stamp to be, let's say, + 1 month? After all, I'm normally allowed to stay 90 days in the country, per a half-a-year period.
2. Otherwise, what else can I do? Leave Paraguay for 1 hour, by land, and then come back thus getting a new entry?

---

3. In case I overstay for 1-2 weeks, what'll be the fine per day?

Comment: Will you have reservations for the rest of your stay? It seems possible that if you request an extension or attempt a re-entry run but haven’t addressed the original reason for the limitation, you will be risking a refusal (which you will then have to disclose on any future visa applications that ask about such things. Ditto an overstay).

Comment: @Traveller how do you know all that? Are you speculating?

Comment: Yes, of course I am speculating, but only about the possibility of refusal. The rest is not speculation, it applies should you actually be refused.

Comment: A "fine per day" is the least of your worries. If you overstay,you will have to report that in every visa application to any third country for a decade or more. That's going to severely damage your chances of getting visa elsewhere.

Comment: @TooTea there's no such a rule to report an overstay in every visa. Gibberish.